# facet barplot on uneven category

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Here is an example data.frame which has 30 unique samples (ID 1 to 30), and each sample has three measurements (at three different thresholds ('G1' column); 5e-03, 5e-05, 5e-08). Each of the 90 observations has a p-value (P column). Finally, each of the thirty samples can belong to one of ten different categories ('G2') [sorry for all the numeric variables!]

```
 # example data.frame
df <- data.frame(
  'ID' = as.character(unlist(lapply(seq(1:30), function(x) rep(x,3)))),
  'P'  = runif(n = 90, min = 0, max = 1),
  'G1' = as.character(c('5e-03','5e-05','5e-08')),
  'G2' = as.character(unlist(lapply(sample(1:10, size = 30, replace = T), function(x) rep(x,3))))
)
```

I can generate a nice bar plot using this command;

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = interaction(ID,G2), y = P, fill = G2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(. ~ G1)
```

which looks like this:

[Plot 1: image with one facet, and 'G2' visualised using colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRk3M.png)

However, what I would really like to do is have two facets; 'G1' on the columns (as it currently is) and, instead of using bar colour to demarcate the 'G2' variable, I would like a second horizontal facet on G2. This is what I have tried:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = interaction(ID,G2), y = P, fill = G2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(G2 ~ G1)
```

and it is not right. When I facet on G2, it is plotting **all** samples in each facet. This is ugly because each sample can only belong to one G2 category. How do I generate the second facet where only bars that belong to that group are plotted? I have tried adjusting the 'drop', 'scale' and 'space' variables in facet_grid, but it does not improve things.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flS1t.png) is what I am looking for - I have manually drawn rectangles over the parts of the plot that should be in the facet. It is essentially the same as Plot 1, except the bars are split into a G2 facet.

Comment: why have you added coord_flip()? remove it and run the same code again. I guess thats what you are looking for

Comment: thanks for the reply. Removing coord_flip() does not solve the problem, the G2 facet is still plotting unobserved data. I am using coord_flip() because I want the plot across the page for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: Maybe change interaction to paste? `paste(ID, G2, sep = ".")`

Comment: Im unable to visualize how you want the graph to look.

Comment: thanks, but this did not solve the problem

Comment: Does `facet_grid(G2 ~ G1, scales = "free_y")` give you the right output?

Comment: I have edited my original post to show you what a good one should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that since you are facetting with G2 and G1, you don't need the `x=interaction(ID,G2)` anymore: `x=ID` is enough.

By default, all facets of a plot share the same scales for their x and y axes. But you can change that with the `scales` argument

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = ID, y = P, fill = G2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  facet_grid(G1 ~ G2, scales="free_x")
```

Note that I swapped G1 and G2 in the definition of the grid. I don't think it is possible to make it work with `coord_flip()` though.

Comment: Thanks Pierre! You have pretty much solved it, thanks very much! Is there any way to have all the individual bars the same width? Your solution results in some bars stretching to fill the facet.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to the Pierre answer :

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = ID, y = P, fill = G2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  facet_grid(G1 ~ G2, scales="free", space="free")
```

This will give same width for every bar.

Comment: very nice Kumar! It is a shame there is no way to do this in conjunction with coord_flip(). But I can live with that!